# True polar parametrization of epitrochoid

Tags: parametrization

I need to cnc machine the internal walls for a wankel engine on a rotary table. For that I need the true polar parametrization of an epitrochoid with roll circle ratio 0.5 with respect to:
1. fixed circle radius R;
2. crank point distance d on the rolling circle;
3. and ideally also an outer epitrochoid offset e, which is necessary to account for the tilting motion of the piston apex seals sliding around the internal side walls. Please plain math language for machine shop guy.

I hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: What is "cnc," and why wouldn't you spell it out to get more help?

Comment: Sorry, cnc stands for computer numeric controlled. The milling machine takes coordinates and other digital information as part of the machining code to control movement of cutting tool and work piece to machine the desired shape. To machine an epitrochoid with an curve offset I therefore have to mathematically precisely define the path geometry.

Comment: ... machining on a rotary table means that the work piece is continuously rotated around a fixed rotation axis while the rotating machining tool is radially moved back and forth.

Comment: You would probably need to give a better description of the problem, probably with pictures to illustrate.